# How do I fully close apps?

Tags: plank, release-juno

When I'm trying to quit messaging (and some other) apps like Telegram or Discord, I'm unable to do so.

If trying to quit Telegram, upon click on close button in the window corner, it just hides the window, and keeps the app in dock. Right clicking the app and clicking Close hides app from the dock, but app is still open.

Similar thing happens with discord, except clicking on close button in window corner hides it from dock, but app remains open, and I receive notifications.

JetBrains toolbox also behaves like discord.

I remember seeing app icons in top-right corner (more like between time and top-right corner) of the screen, but after a bit of googling, this feature was cut from the OS.

While I don't really object to this feature going away, I still need a way to close the apps and I don't know any other way (besides killing the process which is a bad way in my opinion).

So, either, how do I close an app, or how do I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `killall <process>` in the terminal to completly stop the background processes of the applications.

Answer (score 1):

about the notification area, wasn't cut just used another system that apps don't have implemented yet (dropped ayatana)

but you can have it back

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

then we need to edit a file (i used nano, use any editor you want - avoiding a holy war)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

find the line

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;
```

and add Pantheon

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

that's it, just restart X and you will have the old notification area icons

Answer (score 0):

For a graphical method, both Telegram and Discord (and most apps) have a keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (Q for Quit), that will close it completely. They also might (or might not) have a menu option, *File > Quit*.

From the terminal, as another user said, you can also use the `killall`, `pkill` command.

Comment: Hi Ondo, welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. Here's a little **tip:** When you add *keywords* or *commands* in your question, answer & comment, mark them as *code*.